# Display data from sqlite database in a listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to display data in a listview from my sqlite table. I can view the table and it seems as if the information is going in correct. When I run my app the listview comes up but it displays my package name with some numbers and letters instead of the data from my table. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code to get all the information from the table

```
public List<Habits> getAllHabits(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    List<Habits> habitsList = new ArrayList<Habits>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_HABIT;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Habits habit = new Habits();
            habit.setHabit(cursor.getString(1));
            habit.setDate(cursor.getString(2));
            habitsList.add(habit);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    return habitsList;

}
```

Code to display it:

```
public class ViewHabits extends ListActivity {

Cursor cursor;
private Databasehandler db;
String info;
private ListView datalist;
ArrayList<String> databaseList = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    db = new Databasehandler(this);

    List<Habits> values = db.getAllHabits();
    ArrayAdapter<Habits> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Habits>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to override `toString()` method of `Habit` class:

> However the TextView is referenced, it will be filled with the toString() of each object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of custom objects. Override the toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.

From docs: [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)